# C#/WPF Error: An Unhandled Exception of Type 'System.StackOverflow Exception' Occured (Tic-Tac-Toe)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm VERY new to C# and WPF, so bear with me.  I'm doing a C#/WPF Tic-Tac-Toe game.  After the game starts and a few moves are made, I keep getting the following error, and I have no idea why:

"An Unhandled Exception of Type 'System.StackOverflow Exception'"

As far as the computer is concerned, there doesn't have to be ANY strategy.  So, all I want the code to do is randomly pick who goes first (computer or human), and when it's the computer's turn, the computer should just pick a random and enabled button, and assign an "X" or an "O" to it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Also, if there's an easier or shorter way to code this, by all means, let me know!  As I said, I'm pretty new to all this.

NOTE: I HAVE NOT come up with a function/method to determine who the winner is YET.  I don't need help with that.

*****EDIT: As suggested, I declared and instantiated "rnd" once in the "MainWindow" class and left "rnd.Next" in the "randomSquare" method. Before, it was throwing the error all over the place at many different points in the game. Now, it only throws the error when the human goes first and it's the 9th move. Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Below is my edited code.*****

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Operation6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool player1 = true;
        int playerNumber;
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
        Random rnd2 = new Random();    /// Edit: Instantiated only once.

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            playerNumber = rnd1.Next(1, 3);

            if (playerNumber == 1)
                computer();
        }

        private int randomSquare()
        {
            int number;

            number = rnd2.Next(1, 10);

            return number;
        }

        private void computer()
        {
            int squareNumber = randomSquare();

            if (squareNumber == 1 && square1.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square1.Content = "X";
                else
                    square1.Content = "O";

                square1.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 1 && square1.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 2 && square2.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square2.Content = "X";
                else
                    square2.Content = "O";

                square2.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 2 && square2.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 3 && square3.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square3.Content = "X";
                else
                    square3.Content = "O";

                square3.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 3 && square3.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 4 && square4.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square4.Content = "X";
                else
                    square4.Content = "O";

                square4.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 4 && square4.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 5 && square5.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square5.Content = "X";
                else
                    square5.Content = "O";

                square5.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 5 && square5.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 6 && square6.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square6.Content = "X";
                else
                    square6.Content = "O";

                square6.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 6 && square6.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 7 && square7.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square7.Content = "X";
                else
                    square7.Content = "O";

                square7.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 7 && square7.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 8 && square8.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square8.Content = "X";
                else
                    square8.Content = "O";

                square8.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 8 && square8.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else if (squareNumber == 9 && square9.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                if (player1)
                    square9.Content = "X";
                else
                    square9.Content = "O";

                square9.IsEnabled = false;
                player1 = !player1;
            }
            else if (squareNumber == 9 && square9.IsEnabled == false)
                computer();
            else
                draw();
        }

        private void draw()
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "It's a tie!";
        }

        private void squareClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button square = (Button)sender;

            if (player1)
                square.Content= "X";
            else
                square.Content = "O";

            square.IsEnabled = false;
            player1 = !player1;
            computer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not trace through the code with a debugger and find the infinite loop? How hard can it be?

Comment: @Ian There's a good chance that this will not occur in debugging if it's based off of recurring random numbers due to a recurring random seed.

Comment: Doesn't the exception have a stack trace?

Comment: I think the answer from Avner Shahar-Kashtan may be along the right lines. I think people should have to provide a reason for down voting and it should not be anonymous.

Comment: 1. Don't instanciate a `Random` object every time you need a random number. Use a private field (just like `player1` field). 2. Don't use recursion, it is not needed here, confusing and the probable cause of your overflow. Use some kind of `while` loop to retry as needed or figure out a way to only shoot on free slots. 3. You should factorize your code: you're doing the exact same thing nine times in your `computer` method.

Answer (score -1):

A StackOverflowException occurs, in most cases, when you have a recursive method that is called without an appropriate halting clause. In your case, the culprit is likely the *very* messy `computer()` method which calls itself in *several* places, making it difficult to logically reason about the flow that can lead to infinitely recursing. But after scanning it, I'd say the core reason lies in your `randomSquare` method.

The proper way to use the `Random` class is to initialize it once, and then call `Next()` on the same instance. That way you know that it's initialized from one random seed, and then all subsequent calls are based off of that seed. By default, the random seed is based on the current system clock. When you initialize `Random` for every call, you're effectively creating a new random seed based on the system clock for every call, and since it's a pretty tight loop, all these Randoms will return *the same number* many, many times in a row. That means your `computer` method will get several dozen/hundred/thousand Ones in a row (each one calling `computer`, recursively) until the system clock has changed enough. They it might get several dozen/hundred/thousand Threes in a row.

This can eat up your stack very quickly, resulting in  a Stack Overflow.

Try change `rnd` to be a member field, instantiating it once in the constructor, and just call `rnd.Next` in your `randomSquare` method.

Comment: @amaidie90 A [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) is a variable defined for a *class* - in your case MainWindow, not inside a specific method of that class. You declare it outside the method, you assign a value in the constructor, and it's accessible in every method of that class.

Comment: I did what you said, and it helped a lot!  I declared and instantiated "rnd" once in the "MainWindow" class and left "rnd.Next" in the "randomSquare" method.  Before, it was throwing the error all over the place at many different points in the game.  Now, it only throws the error when the human goes first and it's the 9th move.  Any suggestions?  You've helped out a lot, thank you!

Comment: Well, we've eliminated *some* of the logical recursion errors, but not all. :)